# Hahn-Banach. Extend the functional by continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a dense linear subspace of a normed vector space $X$,
and let $Y$ be a Banach space. Suppose $T_{0}\in\mathcal{L}(E,Y)$
is a bounded linear operator from $E$ to $Y$. Show that $T_{0}$
can be extended to $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ (by continuity) without
increasing its norm.

I have a dumb question: Given the Hahn-Banach theorem, what's to prove
here? It seems to be the immediate consequence of that theorem. If
I am wrong, please show me how to prove this. Thank you!

Comment: Hahn-Banach has nothing to do with the problem at hand (and one only speaks of functionALs if $Y$ is the ground field). The key words here are uniform continuity and completeness of $Y$.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks. I still need to think about this. I agree that I can not apply that theorem directly.

Comment: @t.b. $T_0$ is continuous. I just knew that it is also uniformly continuous. So for bounded linear operator, uniform continuity and continuity are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, a bounded linear operator is Lipschitz continuous by definition: $\|Tx_1 - Tx_2\|_Y \leq \|T\|\,\|x_1 - x_2\|_X$. Lipschitz continuity implies uniform continuity. The reason I phrased it the way I did is that it is a general fact that if $f_0: D \to Y$ is *uniformly* continuous where $D \subset X$ is dense in a metric space $X$ and $Y$ is a complete metric space then $f_0$ admits a *unique* extension to a (uniformly) continuous $f: X \to Y$. Applying this in the present situation you get the extension $T$ from this general fact and linearity of $T$ follows from uniqueness of the extension

Comment: @t.b Thanks a lot. I guess that general fact is base on Tietze extension theorem, which I can not use without proof. So I will probably still try azarel's idea.

Comment: Oh, no, no Tietze at all. It's exactly the same argument as the one azarel outlines. You'll see that you won't use that $T_0$ is linear when you define $T$ (or $f$ as azarel write), you'll only need that when verifying that it *is* linear... (and since nobody gave you a vote so far, here we go :))

Comment: @t.b. I figured out everything except one question: I need to use $x_n\rightarrow x\Rightarrow \lim ||x_n||=||x||$. I guess it should be OK, but I feel I have not seen such a property before.

Comment: That's a consequence of the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) and the definition of $x_n \to x$: $|\|x_n\| - \|x\|| \leq \|x_n - x\| \to 0$, so $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$.

Comment: Finally, problem solved. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hahn-Banach only apply if $Y=\mathbb R$. For this particular problem you want to show that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ then $T_0(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and then define $f(x)$ as the limit of the sequence. Finally you need to show that the map is a well-defined bounded linear function.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure out the details.